# How to inject ui.grid at controller level?

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller, angular-grid

Can we Inject 'ui.grid' at controller level not at Module level.

something like this.

```
.controller('gridController', ['ui.grid', function ($scope) {


    }])
```

***Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ui.gridProvider <- ui.grid <- gridController***

Comment: Why do you want to do this at "module level" ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No.

`ui.grid` is a module so it has to be at the module level.

In controllers you can inject factories, services etc which make a module.

Comment: I have below error if i add at module level.                                                                                                                Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.grid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: You may not have ui-grid.js  Javascript code to your html/(index.html). Check to make sure it is after angularjs.

Comment: In the browser check Network tab to ensure if all the relevant Java scripts were downloaded. Ensure proper sequence. angular.js, ui-grid.js, your app.js which defined module as per http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro

Comment: Anyway that is a different question however if you can create a plnkr I or someone can take a quick look. Its should be a easy fix.

Comment: I am not using ui.grid in index.html page. Do i need to add reference even though not using?

Comment: Yes. If you have in module.